# Quartz Cron String Understanding Issue

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I currently have this quartz cron string 0 0/35 11-13 1/1 * ? *. Now what it generally means is Occurs every 1 day(s) every 35 minute(s) between 11 AM and 1 PM. At least from my understanding that is what it means. Though when I look at possible run times I get these.

- 06/08/2013 11:00:00 AM
- 06/08/2013 11:35:00 AM
- 06/08/2013 12:00:00 PM
- 06/08/2013 12:35:00 PM
- 06/08/2013 1:00:00 PM

That does not make sense to me. It seems to reset on the hour. Is there anyway for this not to occur? I would like the job to run at 11AM, then 11:35AM and then 12:10PM not 12PM.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , this is the problem my colleagues encounters every now and then.

As per the [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) for Quartz scheduler ( and yes off-course, as per my understanding of Quartz till now :-p ), cron trigger will be set to fire at **"every 35th minute of the hour"** and not "every 35th minute in a day".

For your requirement you should use a simple-trigger .

```
    Date firetime=null; //initialize to Your start time of trigger "11.00am"
            Date endtime=null; // initialize to Your end time of trigger "1.00pm"
    Trigger tr1 = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .startAt(firetime)
                            .endAt(endtime)
            .withIdentity("First Trigger", "First Group")
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                            .withIntervalInMinutes(35)
            ).build();
```

And use another trigger to schedule this trigger daily.:-)

Comment: Yeah, I actually went after this and posted an issue on the quartz.net github and got an answer from Marko Lamha that was exactly as you stated. I really wish it did not work like this though. Oh well thank you for the help.